# How do I make my iPhone app display a top banner alert, such as the Mail app does?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, notifications

I have searched for this, and I can't find any documentation about doing these banner / notification / alerts... but I would really like to implement it.
In case my description in words is not clear, here is a picture of what I would like to do:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NSZN.png): [image: screen shot]

I tried using this code:

```
UILocalNotification *note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[note setAlertBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ scanned", result]];
[note setAlertAction:@"New Scanned Image"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:note];
```

And it worked fine, such that it displayed the notification in the notifications center, but there was no banner alert.

So what are the classes that I use for this?

Thanks!

Comment: After some experimenting, I found out that if I set the UILocalNotification to appear in say, 20 seconds, and I close my app, it does exactly what I want.  But if my app stays open, no notification alert appear.  And I want that to appear in my app.... is there any way that I can override this behavior?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Alerts appear only for app inactive apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't define what type of alert to be used for your app's notifications. It can be set only by user through Notification Center settings.

Note! Alerts appear only when you app is closed or it is in background. If your app is active (it is in foreground), it will get only a notification (see [`- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning%3a) for details).

Comment: So how does the Mail app, or Facebook, make these appear... I set my Notifications Settings to include my app and alert style to "Banners"... what else can I do?

Comment: Note! Alerts appear only for inactive apps.

Comment: Alright, well although it wasn't a very helpful answer, I guess it answered my questions.... too bad, but thanks anyways!